# Is there any difference between Rem and -- comments for SQL*Plus?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, sqlplus

On SQL*Plus prompt, both `Rem` and `--` qualify as comment indicators:

```
Rem this is a comment
-- this is also a comment
create table emp (
id number primary key,
name cvarchar2(40));
```

Is there any difference at all between the two commenting techniques?

Comment: And don't forget /* comment */ is valid too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The difference is that `--` and `/* */` can be used in a PL/SQL block, while [`REM[ARK]`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve034.htm#SQPUG054) cannot.  The following will work in SQL*Plus:

```
REM comment
-- comment
/* comment */
begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test'); --comment
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test'); /* comment */
end; 
/
```

These will not:

```
begin
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test'); REM comment
end; 
/

begin
   REM comment
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test');
end; 
/
```

The [11.2 documentation on all comment types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210024) has more comment information.  The basics are...

> You can enter comments in a script in
>   three ways:
>
> - using the SQL*Plus REMARK command for single line comments.
> - using the SQL comment delimiters /*... */ for single or multi-line
>     comments.
> - using ANSI/ISO (American National Standards Institute/International
>     Standards Organization) comments - -
>     for single line comments.

The documentation also includes notes on four places that comments should not be used, but these do not include any further differences.

Comment: To be fair, I've never encountered a language that supports REM as a comment delimiter where those three letters aren't the first command characters on a given line (cf @REM in batch files)

Comment: @jcolebrand Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

REM is supported due to being the way MS BATCH files are commented, and this tool being used with automation environments.

-- is supported due to being part of the SQL standard. ( http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt page 83 cf `<comment introducer> ::= <minus sign><minus sign>[<minus sign>...]` )

Answer (score -1):

No there should be no difference at all.

Comment: Why two comment styles then?

Comment: @Lazer: backwards compatibility I expect

Comment: I believe that REM is valid only for the tool SQLPlus, while -- and /**/ are coming from the language, they work also in MS SQL - TSQL for example.